# Web2py transfer site

Tags: deployment, web2py, transfer

I have a Web2py site that I want to transfer to another computer. I'll do an SQL dump for the (external) database, but does anyone have experience of transferring the Web2py site itself? Which files do I need to copy to the new machine?

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be fine just copying the application folder. You can exclude the `/cache`, `/errors`, and `/sessions` subfolders. Make sure you restore the database before running the application (or if you want web2py to re-create the database tables, make sure migrations are enabled and do not copy the contents of the `/databases` folder).

Comment: Thanks again Anthony, you are rapidly becoming my new best friend!